# How to add multiple conditions to Rails scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, default-scope

I've been looking for this for a while and can't seem to find an answer, although I think that it should be a pretty easy fix if you're more experienced with Rails than I am. I am trying to add multiple default_scope conditions to my Product model. My product model file is as follows:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :order_items
    default_scope { where(active: true) }
    validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 300 }
    PRICE_REGEXP = /\A\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?\z/
    validates :price, presence: true,
                      numericality: true,
                      format: { with: PRICE_REGEXP }
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1000 }, 
                            allow_nil: true
end
```

I would like to also add

```
default_scope -> { order(created_at: desc) }
```

so that new products on the product index page are in the format of newest first. I get an syntax error message anytime I do something like:

```
default_scope -> { order(created_at: desc) }, { where(active: true) }
```

or

```
default_scope -> { order(created_at: desc), where(active: true) }
```

or

```
default_scope -> { order(created_at: desc) where(active: true) }
```

I know that this is probably just a syntax thing that I'm not understanding. If anyone could give me advice on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this

```
default_scope -> { where(active: true).order(created_at: :desc)  }
```

So effectively you just had a syntax issue. When they added the new [lambda](https://isotope11.com/blog/stabby-lambda) scope syntax to rails it was a little unfamiliar to a lot of ruby developers due to its functional programming origins (given rails is object oriented language). Effectively the segment of code in `{}` acts like a block and executes the code inside. The `where` clause gets implicitly called on the model the scope is declared in. That `where` clause returns a `ActiveRecord` relation object (that is a collection of database records) which implements the `order` method that will sort the records in the relation by the attribute that is passed (in this case `created_at`) in descending (`desc`) or ascending (`asc`) order based on the parameter passed in.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you describe why it works.

Comment: It would have been sufficient to just write that you compose scopes in active record by chaining the method calls.

Comment: O I guess that explanation was over kill, but I am glad you included your comment.

Comment: Thanks man! Fixed my problem. The explanation was really helpful too!

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII what if I have to have an 'or' condition for Order, say I want to order on the the name if it exists otherwise order with created at. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Mahesh Mesta I don't know if what you are asking is possible. imagine the scenario where 10 items 5 have names and created_at dates, 5 only have created_at dates unless you are sorting by both criteria and a nil name is an edge case you prepare for somehow with more complex logic. Give an example in a question and link it.